# ImportError: No module named pysqlite2

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

Why does

```
from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
```

cause

> ImportError: No module named pysqlite2

Isn't pysqlite2 already installed in Python 2.6.5?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The module is called `sqlite3`. `pysqlite2` was the module's name before it became part of the Python standard library.

You probably want to use this in your code:

```
import sqlite3
```

And the standard documentation is here: http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html

edit: And just to cover all the bases:

The `sqlite3` module also has a `dbapi2` sub-member, but you don't need to use it directly. The `sqlite3` module exposes all the `dbapi2` members directly.

Comment: I see. So I was able to just `import sqlite3` and `connection = sqlite3.connect('MyDatabase.db')` etc. Thanks a million.